# Ubuntu 10.04 - high load , low cpu, IO, and no swapping

Tags: linux, ubuntu, performance

Ubuntu 10.04 64bit - Kernel 2.6.36
Running as a Xen 3.4 guest.

8GB memory , no swap being used, no IO wait time,  and 0% cpu.
Yet high load.  Why is this:

```
15:11:24 up 5 days,  3:22,  2 users,  load average: 21.23, 20.06, 19.51
Tasks: 113 total,   1 running, 112 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   7416372k total,  5250472k used,  2165900k free,   153260k buffers
Swap:  1959924k total,    26288k used,  1933636k free,   246932k cached
```

IO top shows nothing.

free -mem

```
        total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7242       5127       2115          0        149        241
-/+ buffers/cache:       4736       2506
Swap:         1913         25       1888
```

Comment: Presumably you have a lot of threads/processes waiting for I/O that's not happening. Networked filesystems can do this.

Comment: Have you got 4 CPUs?

Comment: Dual Xeon - 8 threads.

Answer (score 1):

You either 1) own the host or 2) you are renting it from a hosting company.

If it's 1 then you should look at the other machines on the host, find out which one is thrashing the disks and fix it.

If it's 2 you need to complain to your hosting company and see if they can't either move you or move the offending party to another physical box and/or data store.

Comment: If 1 then there should be wait time.
If 2 there should be stolen time.

Comment: It's on a 'bare-metal' Xen guest.  Hosted with a provider. they say the physical hardware isn't shared.  It's just under a Xen host to be able to launch/re seize, etc easily.